# Xam.Plugin.Media is Giving a Crash on IOS devices while picking a video

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using Plugin.Media to pick a video from my device. When I upload the video, it shows it is being compressed and the App immediately crashes. How do I successfully upload a video from my iOS device ?

Error Message: 
`Access to the path 'private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/../tmp/file1.mov is denied`

Xam.Plugin version: 4.4.10-beta

iOS Version: 13.4

```
if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickVideoSupported)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Videos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to videos.", "OK");
    return;
}

videoFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickVideoAsync();

if (videoFile == null)
    return;

using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
{

    Stream stream = videoFile.GetStream();
    stream.CopyTo(memory);
    videoArray = memory.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: how large is the file?

Comment: @Jason , the file is about 16MB

Comment: this is a known issue - https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/739

Comment: Have you tried using the 4.4.6 version or the non-beta version of the package?